# Swift getter + array initialization

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, initialization, getter

How can I do this right? (Error: Variable used within its own initial value):

```
private var cars = [Car]() {
    get { return cars }
}
```

...works for:

```
private var connection:Bool! {
    get { return connection }
}
```

Comment: `private var cars = [Car]()`

Comment: Why did you declare your Bool implicitly unwrapped optional?

Comment: @LeoDabus `connected` / `maybe connected` / `not connected` ;-)

Comment: I know, I was kidding

Comment: Ok, sorry. Not really used to setter/getter in Swift, yet. :(

Comment: `:Bool!` is a type.  `=[Car]()` is a value.

Comment: @suppe your question it is unclear. please edit your question with your actual code showing where you are declaring this properties and what you are trying to accomplish. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Your variable

```
cars
```

is a computed property. That been said, it doesnt store any value. For your example you will need to create a variable. Lest called it

```
private var localCars = [Car]()
```

This variable is the one that will store all the values you need and then you can use the computed property to get all the information you need from cars like this.

```
private var cars:Cars! {
    get { return localCars }
}
```

You can also use the set in your computed propert to store the value to localCars

```
private var cars:Cars! {
    get { return localCars }
    set { localCars = newValue }
}
```

If you want to learn what its a computer property check this [page](http://www.codingexplorer.com/computed-properties-in-swift/). It explains them really well.

Comment: Why optional Cars if you are already initializing your array at declaration? BTW you can always omit the get keyword when you don't have a setter. And at last bot not least why a computed property that will always have the same value as the original property

Comment: You should never use IUO in 99% of the cases and this is definitely not one of them

Comment: The op doesnt really need a computed property but he is using so i am just trying to give him a possible solution. It is no ideal but like you said it not that clear.

Comment: It is not even clear what OP it is asking. I am just giving my opinion on your answer.

Comment: Lets just wait to see what OP is asking and then i will update my answer or delete it.

Comment: the answer for this question as it is it is my first comment. Just a simple declaration and initialization at the same time. looks like thats all he needs